How to Start a Broadcast Receiver When the App is in a Killed State?
I'm developing an Android app that needs to listen for specific events, even when the app is killed (completely terminated by the user or system). Specifically, I need to trigger actions like reconnecting to a WebSocket or other background tasks, even if the app is not running in the background.
I understand that Android has limitations regarding background processing and that apps are generally unable to listen for events while they are in a killed state. However, I would like to know if there's any way to start a BroadcastReceiver when the app is in a killed state, and respond to system events such as:
Network connectivity changes Incoming data from Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) AlarmManager or JobScheduler events I’m aware that:
JobScheduler can schedule tasks in the background, but does it work when the app is killed? FCM messages can wake the app up, but how do I handle FCM data payloads to restart a service when the app is killed? BroadcastReceiver can catch some system events, but can it start when the app is killed?
My specific questions are:
Is it possible to start a BroadcastReceiver or any component when the app is killed? What is the best practice to handle events like reconnecting a WebSocket when the app is terminated? Are there any workarounds for listening to system events such as network changes or receiving FCM messages while the app is completely killed? Is their any way to launch an activity or full screen notification or kind of critical alert which capture whole screen for displaying what is getting performed to user interface ??
What I’ve tried:
I’ve implemented a BroadcastReceiver to listen for CONNECTIVITY_ACTION when the app is running, which works fine. But when the app is killed, it doesn't get triggered. I’ve also explored using a Foreground Service, but I need it to be started again when the app is terminated. Any help or guidance would be appreciated, especially on how to handle these use cases while complying with Android’s background execution limits.
Environment: Target SDK: 34 (Android 14) Using Firebase for push notifications

What exactly does "the app is killed" mean, in computer engineering terms? Do you mean that the OS terminated the process? Do you mean that the user swiped your task off of the overview (recents) screen? Do you mean that the user went into the Settings app to the page for your app and clicked "Force Stop"? Or do you mean something else?

Yes,In computer engineering terms, when we say "the app is killed", it means that the operating system (OS) has completely terminated the process associated with the app, removing it from memory. @CommonsWare


Is it possible to start a BroadcastReceiver or any component when the app is killed?

Yes, by having another app or a system process use an Intent to interact with the activity, service, or broadcast receiver. In the specific case of broadcast receivers, usually this needs to be an explicit broadcast, as only a few implicit broadcasts are supported on modern versions of Android.

What is the best practice to handle events like reconnecting a WebSocket when the app is terminated?

This is impossible to answer in the abstract.

Are there any workarounds for listening to system events such as network changes or receiving FCM messages while the app is completely killed?

The point of Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is for apps to receive messages when their processes are not currently running. No "workaround" is needed.

Is their any way to launch an activity or full screen notification or kind of critical alert which capture whole screen for displaying what is getting performed to user interface ?

You are welcome to raise a notification in response to receiving an FCM message.
